# Achieving seam hot deployment with Intellij-idea

Tags: seam, intellij-idea, hotdeploy

How can I achieve hot deployment with Intellij-IDEA and Seam 2?

I've set up a separate module to deploy hot deployable class files to WEB-INF/dev/, but it still deploys as one big clump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to get hot deployment with Intellij-IDEA and Jboss: 
(This is assuming your WAR project already deploys from an exploded directory successfully)

1. Create a new module and move your hot source folder into it.
2. Open your primary module settings and add your new hot-module as a new dependency.
3. Open the web-facet of your primary module, and in Modules and Libraries to package click 'add', 'add module'. change its 'output relative path' to WEB-INF/dev
4. Edit your run configuration and enable 'Build on frame deactivation'.
5. Run the server.

Now, whenever you alt-tab out of IDEA, your views and seam POJO controllers are redeployed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I use plug-ins for hot deployment.

- Download JReable and install it.
- Restart intellij.

**Note:** plug-ins are charged.